# ¿Como descargo un fichero por ajax, con un control de errores en caso de error del sevicio?

Tags: jquery, jsp, base64, download

os comento un problema que tengo.

Por una parte, tengo una JSP y unas clases java que llama a un servicio SOAP y este me devuelve un fichero en base64.
Tras obtenerlo, lo convierto a un fichero excel, y lo descargo, sin guardarlo en servidor.
Este servicio, en el caso de que ocurra algo inesperado, me devuelvo un codigo de error. Hasta aqui, sin problemas.

En la parte front, quiero descargar ese fichero, (a ser posible, por ajax) pero controlando que, si el servicio me devuelve un error, mostrar un mensaje.

En muchas soluciones, he visto que para descargar un fichero, poner un `<a href="URL_JSP">` pero de esta forma, no puedo controlar los errores.
Si hago una llamada normal por ajax, este no descarga el fichero.

He intentado multiples soluciones, ¿alguna idea, o algun ejemplo al respecto?

Muchas gracias.

P.D.: Se que podria convertir el base64 a fichero en javascript, pero me gustaria que esto fuera un plan B, ya que podria dar problemas con navegadores antiguos (comentarme si no estais de acuerdo).

**EDITO**:
Al final he obtado por obtener por ajax el codigo base64, y convertirlo a fichero en javascript. De todas formas, si alguien tiene alguna solución para convertir el fichero y descargarlo en la JSP por ajax, manteniendo el control de errores, seran bienvenidos los comentarios.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type:"POST", 
    responseType: 'text',
    async:true,
    cache:false,
    success:function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        
        if(data.indexOf("error") != -1){
            console.log(data);
            $("#contentError").fadeIn( 500 );
            $("#contentSuccess").fadeOut( 500 );
        }else{
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            link.href = "data:text/plain;base64," + data;
            link.download = 'fichero.xls';
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            $("#contentError").fadeOut( 500 );
            $("#contentSuccess").fadeIn( 500 );
        }
    },
    error:function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        $("#contentError").fadeIn( 500 );
        $("#contentSuccess").fadeOut( 500 );
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Comment: Como a todos los usuarios recién llegados, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para ganar tu primera medalla en el sitio y que leas [ask] para conocer cómo se espera que se planteen las preguntas en SOes. Bienvenido!

Comment: Gracias, llevo la tira de años en el mundillo y en stackoverflow pero es la primera pregunta que realizo. Revisaré lo que comentas.